# Passing block as variable failing "ArgumentError: Missing block"

Tags: ruby

I have the method

```
  def self.fetch(key, &block)
    begin
      Rails.cache.fetch(key, block)
    rescue Redis::CommandError => e
      raise unless e.message == "OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'."

      Utils.log_exception ex
      yield
    end
  end
```

This fails on line 3 with the error

> ArgumentError: Missing block: Calling `Cache#fetch` with `force: true`
>   requires a block.

I'm not sure if passing block in as a parameter like that is the correct way but I couldn't see another way.

What is the correct way to pass a variable containing a block to a method?

Comment: See the docs for [Block Arguments](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument) (2nd example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&` ampersand unary prefix operator in an argument list is used to "unroll" an instance of `Proc` as if it were passed as a block to a method, just like the `&` ampersand sigil in a parameter list is used to "roll up" a block passed as an argument into an instance of `Proc`:

```
Rails.cache.fetch(key, &block)
#                      ↑
```